# Python Serialize numpy array to bytestring

Tags: python, json, numpy, python-requests

I need to serialize a numpy array to json. The value should be a byte string. The API expects the data to be a string, and then decodes the data with `np.fromstring(post_data.get("mask_image"))`.

```
post_data = {
        "room_image": bytes(Image.fromarray(image).tobytes()),
        "mask_image": bytes(Image.fromarray(mask).tobytes()),
    }
```

I've also tried to use `json.dumps` but it gives the same decoding errors

Server error:

```
   raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply enclose the bytes within double quotes as JSON format requires them.
So try

```
post_data = {
        "room_image": '"' + bytes(Image.fromarray(image).tobytes()) + '"',
        "mask_image": '"' +bytes(Image.fromarray(mask).tobytes()) + '"'
    }
```

Hope it helps :)